# AngularJS : automate process to minify project

Tags: angularjs, automation, minify

I have this interest in automate/simplify angular project with a compiler tool, which might work on everything else, but angular inject and namespacing is awkward enough to escape compiler knowledge. What is the best/professional method for doing this?

thanks, just one last thing,

```
app.controller('ctrl',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
    ...
}]);
```

works when minified, but how do I minify

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

}]);
```

and does it work when I minify successive actions?

```
app.controller(...).directive(...).run(...)
```

Comment: if use string syntax for injections shouldn't have to do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `ngmin` (https://github.com/btford/ngmin) to automatically add Dependency-Injection annotations to AngularJS project. After this is done you should be able to use any JavaScript minifier.

Answer (score 0):

For each method you are chaining, use the brackets - exactly like you thought.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){ }]).run(['$http', '$rootScope',  function($http, $rootScope){ }]);
```