# minify js files in angular js project for production environment

Tags: angularjs

I am developing application using angular js,spring mvc and tomcat 8. i want my js files to be minified in production environment. is it possible to do at server level?

Comment: Show some codes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : automate process to minify project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706972/angularjs-automate-process-to-minify-project)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, with a filter.
Try using wro4j

index.html production envornment

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wro/all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wro/all.js"/>
```

Wro Filter

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
      <group name="all">
        <css>/asset/*.css</css>
        <js>/asset/*.js</js>
      </group>
    </groups>  
<filter>
  <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/wro/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```